# Swipe gesture not recognized

Tags: java, android, swipe, gesture

For my `Buttons` `onClickListener` I have the following code:

```
on_enter_button.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                enter(words, linearLayout, llp, view);
             }
        });
```

Instead of pressing enter `Button`, I simply want to `Swipe` the screen in any direction and run the same method: `enter(words, linearLayout, llp, view);`

Currently I think my program does not recognize `Swipe` gestures at all. I assume it's because I placed `enter(words, linearLayout, llp, view);` incorrectly. Also, I put all the `Gesture` recognition code inside the `onCreate()`. Is that the correct way to program the code?

Can someone please help?

EDITED CODE:

```
public class Game extends Activity{

public void enter(String[] w, LinearLayout ll, LinearLayout.LayoutParams params, View v){
... //some code
... //some code
... //some code
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return myGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    //error myGestureDetector not recognized since it's created in onCreate so it does not exist here
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);

     SimpleOnGestureListener mySimpleGestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener()
     {

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) { 
            return super.onDoubleTap(e);
        }

        @Override
        //swipe does not work!
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,float velocityY) 
        {
                enter(words, linearLayout, llp, view);
                return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            super.onLongPress(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }

        private boolean permissibleYVelocity(float velocityY)
        {
            if ((velocityY < -200) || (velocityY > 200))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }   
    };

    final GestureDetector myGestureDetector = new  GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), mySimpleGestureListener);

    //button listener works
    on_enter_button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    enter(words, linearLayout, llp, view);
                 }
            });
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `View.onTouchEvent()`.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Call your method in SimpleOnGestureListener.onFling():

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,float velocityY) 
{
    enter(words, linearLayout, llp, view);
    return true;
}
```

EDIT:
Setup your GestureDectector in onCreate() as well:

```
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        return super.onDoubleTap(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,float velocityY)
    {
        enter(words, linearLayout, llp, view);
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        super.onLongPress(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
    }

    private boolean permissibleYVelocity(float velocityY)
    {
        if ((velocityY < -200) || (velocityY > 200))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do I override these in my  SimpleOnGestureListener class?

Comment: You would override `View.onTouchEvent()` in whatever view you want to listen for a fling, which in your case is your Activity class. `SimpleOnGestureListener.onFling()` you already have, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Sorry I am new at this. Where do I call onFling()? Inside the onTouch? Or do I just change the onFling() I have in the SimpleGesture?

Comment: the enter() method does not work inside the onFling(). The parameters were not created yet... Am I supposed to put the gesture override methods in the SimpleOnGesture class? inside the onCreate? or just in the Activity somewhere? I am trying to find reliable tutorials online but everything is outdated...

Comment: I think it is best practice to setup your gestures in your onCreate().

Comment: I edited my code above. Can you please take a look and tell me exactly how you would arrange everything? Sorry again. I'll keep trying to fix it myself though. Thanks :) And does my activity need to implement a gestureListener?

Comment: You need to make your GestureDetector a field variable, like it was before. Just do the initialization in the onCreate().